# Using variable in immediate execute

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I would like have row count in every partition for a long period of dates. So i used used for loop from where I'm trying to extract dates which will be used in partition. But I'm getting below errors. Can't resolve it. Can anyone help me with it and some documents which might increase my know-how on this? Thanks.

```
declare
call_enddate date;
totalcount number;
begin
for curdate in (WITH x(d) AS
                 (SELECT TO_DATE('2016-09-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                   FROM dual
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT d + interval '1' day
                   FROM x
                  WHERE d < TO_DATE('2017-09-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
                SELECT to_char (d, 'YYYYMMDD') Date_Char FROM x
              ) 
loop
        execute immediate 'select --parallel(32)
                    trunc(call_end_time), count(*) into call_enddate, totalcount 
                    from lic_msc_data partition(p'||TO_CHAR(curdate.Date_Char,'YYYYMMDD'||'))
                    where sp_number like ''88016%''
                    group by trunc(call_end_time)';                        
dbms_output.put_line(call_enddate||'----'||totalcount);  
end loop;
end;
```

**Error Code:**

```
ORA-06550: line 19, column 55:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
) , * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why can't you use the partition key as a column to group by? That way, you should be able to query the table in one go and get the results you need. Please can you tell us how the table is partitioned?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have embedded the PL/SQL `into` clause in your statement. Do it like this instead:

```
for curdate in (WITH x(d) AS
                 (SELECT DATE '2016-09-01'
                   FROM dual
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT d + 1
                   FROM x
                  WHERE d < DATE '2017-09-05')
                SELECT d FROM x
              ) 
loop
        execute immediate 'select --parallel(32)
                    trunc(call_end_time), count(*)
                    from lic_msc_data partition(p'||TO_CHAR(curdate.d,'YYYYMMDD'||'))
                    where sp_number like :n
                    group by trunc(call_end_time)'
               into call_enddate, totalcount using '88016%';
```

Maybe this one is even more elegant:

```
BEGIN
    d := DATE '2016-09-01';
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ...
        dbms_output.put_line(call_enddate||'----'||totalcount); 
        d := d + 1;
        EXIT WHEN d > DATE '2017-09-05';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

btw, `--parallel(32)` does not make any sense. Do you mean `--+ parallel(32)` resp. `/*+ parallel(32) */`?

Comment: I wonder how many cores the OP actually has on their server? I bet not many Production servers have the spare capacity to service that many concurrent threads.